# Why am I receiving an "unable to create process" error?

Tags: python, selenium, path, pycharm, virtualenv

I am new to coding in Python, and have hit an error I cannot figure out how to solve. The project I have been working on in Pycharm was functioning properly all week, and suddenly when I ran it for the first time this morning, I got the following error:

*Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe C:/Users/david/OneDrive/Desktop/pythonProject/main.py'*

[See Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79Ikq.png)

I am unsure how to fix this, so I tried to create a new project as part of troubleshooting and received the following error:

*Failed to create virtual environment:*

[Project Creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayDDc.png)

[Failed to Create Virtual Environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtCUt.png)

How do I resolve this? I think its something to do with how my files are set up, however, I did not change anything between a successful run and receiving this error.

Comment: Run `C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe` manually outside of PyCharm - does it work correctly? As a side note - storing virtual environments and code inside OneDrive is not recommended. If you need a file sharing solution - `git` is a standard industry choice and even thеn venv should be excluded.